# Reusing jQuery-UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having all kinds of grief trying to re-use a jQuery-UI dialog. First time in everything works fine. Second time in, text fields have the previous values from first time through. In an attempt to make it work, in the click() function just after I do dialog("open") I manually clear the text fields values using `$("#fname, #lname, #email").val('');`. That effectively clears the fields for re-use but then when I submit the form using the serialize() method, the data being sent looks like this `fname=two&lname=2&email=two@aol.com&fname=First+Name&lname=Last+Name&email=Email+ad
dress`. "First Name", "Last Name" and "Email address" are watermarks set using some fieldtag plugin that I don't understand.

The main question is, there must be some easy way to use the dialog a subsequent time with it initialized the way it was the first time. The close() method doesn't seem to do it. The dialog is being created with autoOpen set to false.

```
$("#user-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 400,
    width: 625,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $("#fname, #lname, #email").val('');
        },
    buttons: {
        "Update": function () {
            var bValid = true;

            allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
            if (bValid) {
                $.get('AJAX/AddEditUser.php', $("#fname, #lname, #email").serialize(), function(){
                    $.get('users.php', function(data){
                        $("#contentcontainer").html(data);
                    });
                });
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $("#wholeArea").hide();
                $("#placeholder").show();
                $("div.content-area").load('home.html');
            }
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function () {
        allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
    }
})
```

Comment: Can we see the code that's opening the dialog?

Comment: Sorry for all the notifications you probably received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing, which I guess was a pretty stupid mistake. When data was added via the Dialog, in order to display the newly entered data I was populating a container div with the entire page that created the page in the first place, using the jQuery hmtl() method. I thought that would wipe out what was already there but apparently not, perhaps because the original HTML was already in the browser memory? I'm not sure, at any rate it caused all sorts of odd behavior with various jQuery plug-ins. Now that I quit doing that and simply update my dataTables with fnReloadAjax() all sorts of problems started disappearing. Thanks for everyone's contributions.

Answer (score 0):

jquery-ui dialog is not meant to clear anything within it when it closes, what it is meant to do is display a div as a dialog and let you customize how it should look and behave, this means that if you input values and don't clear them on close, the values will still remain.

The reason why the watermark text is submitted is because your watermark code puts the text within the input element and doesn't clear it when a form submits, another approach would be to find another watermark plugin that adds a span behind the input element instead which will remove the issue entirely.

Comment: I've removed all references to the fieldtag plugin. Now when I make subsequent entries, the data that gets passed to php looks like this: `fname=two&lname=2&email=two@aol.com&fname=&lname=&email=` In other words, the data fields get appended with blank values. PHP only sees the last set and when that goes to the database it errors out because the fields don't allow null.

Comment: @user38653 it looks as if you have 2 elements of each field(as if two elements has the same Id), could you please add relevant html?

Comment: There really only is a single field for each form element. If I were to run it a third time, a third set of variables would show up. The update method is either adding a set of fields to the form or serialize() thinks that it is.

Comment: @user39653 I've tried to replicate your issue and I can honestly say that you must be adding more elements with the same id, probably at "$("#contentcontainer").html(data);" but it all depends on what the "data" is, i suspect that it is html elements, you should be able to verify it if you use a tool like firebug when you run the page.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Joakim, I also suspect it is the watermark plugin that is playing up. Try to disable it and see if your form data is as expected.

Also, you can use the `open` event to initialise the dialog every time it opens:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $("#fname, #lname, #email").val('');
    },
    autoOpen: false,
    /* your other options... */
});
```

Comment: I think you guys are right that it's the watermark that's giving me grief. I'm using a fieldtag plugin that I don't understand. I **think** I have it disabled for this control (I don't see the watermark) but now when I view the data being submitted by viewing what serialize() produces I get the following goffy looking string: `fname=one&lname=one&email=one@aol.com&fname=&lname=email=` so when PHP gets the data it reads the last set and sees all three fields as null.